# Fundamental property of Dirac Delta function on shifted functions and compositions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta, function-and-relation-composition

A well-known property of delta function is the following:
$$\int\limits_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a)$$
for $\epsilon > 0$.

For the case of a shifted function I would like to know if the following holds always:
$$\int\limits_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(x-b)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a-b)$$
for $\epsilon > 0$, $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

In general, I am wondering about the following:
$$\int\limits_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(g(x))\delta(x-a)dx=f(g(a))$$
for $\epsilon > 0$, $b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g$ known real function.

Comment: Maybe we need some hypothesis on $g$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define $h(x):= f(x-b)$ and $k(x):=f(g(x))$. Then you can use the well known property of the dirac delta, which you already stated, for the functions $h$ and $k$ and conclude the two identities:

$$
\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(g(x))\delta(x-a)dx = \int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}k(x)\delta(x-a)dx = k(a) = f(g(a))
$$